# <video> tag mobile issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I have a background video that need autoplay.
The currently code is working only on Desktop:

```
.bg_video{
 position: fixed; 
 right: 0; 
 bottom: 0;
 min-width: 100%; 
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto; 
 height: auto; 
 z-index: -1000;
 background-size: cover; 
 }

<video autoplay loop poster="polina.jpg" class="bg_video">
 <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
 <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Searching a bit, I found this: https://medium.com/this-also/whitewater-9b47f1e32ffe

It's sounds a good idea, but I get an error when try load with whitewater

```
video not found 
whitewater.whitewater.ProgramEnd
```

Some error reports about that issue
https://github.com/samiare/whitewater-encoder/issues/7

As suggested I already installed brew and ffmpeg

How to solve that?

Comment: You've tagged this question with "java" but it seems more likely that this relates to JavaScript. Did you mean to use the "javascript" tag for this question instead?

Comment: @Bobulous Yes, I fixed it but seems that will be hard :( 0 answers